# How to add data to an element in a ForEach

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I'm learning swift and for an assignment I need to Create an app to track habits.
The view I created so far looks like this:
[image]

With the '+' symbol in the top right you can add a habit you want to track.
The habits are show using a ForEach looping over an Array of Habit elements.

There are two kinds of tracking. One is counting and the other is tracking time.

My Idea is that if a user clicks the small '+' sign (see the red 1) the counter is raised by 1 (the number at the red 2) To do that the number of elements in the TrackingData array is counted.
For the time tracking habit the user can fill in a duration (The red 3) that is add to the total Time (The red 4). To do that an element with a duration is added to the TrackingData array.

This is not working as the elements used in the ForEach are constants(?)

How could I fix this?

This is my View Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var habits = Habits()
    
    @State private var showingAddHabit = false
    @State private var duration = 5
    
    private var totalDuration = 0;
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                if(habits.items.count == 0) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("There are no Habits to track.")
                        Text("Add one so you can start tracking it")
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                } else {
                    ForEach(habits.items) { habit in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(habit.id)")
                                    .padding(.leading)
                                    .frame( maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.8))
                                if(habit.trackingType == "Count") {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                        .frame( maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.5))
                                    
                                    Text("\(habit.trackingData?.count ?? 0)")
                                    
                                    Button() {
                                        //habit.trackingData?.append(Habit.TrackingData(id: Date.now))
                                    } label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "plus.app")
                                            .padding(.horizontal)
                                            .frame( maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.8))
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "clock")
                                        .frame( maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.5))

                                    if((habit.trackingData?.count ?? 0) != 0) {
                                        // This is going to be another question...
                                    }
                                    Text("\(totalDuration) minutes")

                                    TextField("Duration", value: $duration, format: .number)
                                        .padding(.horizontal)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                                        .frame( maxWidth: 80)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.8))
                                        .onSubmit {
//                                            habit.trackingData?.append(Habit.TrackingData(id: Date.now, duration: duration))
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .background(.lightBackground)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("HabiTrack")
            .background(.darkBackground)
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    showingAddHabit = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.app")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddHabit) {
                EditHabitsView(habits: habits)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

My Habit class:

```
import Foundation

class Habit: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    class TrackingData: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
        var id: Date
        var duration: Int?
    }
    
    var id: String
    var description: String?
    var trackingType: String
    var trackingData: [TrackingData]?
    
}
```

And finally my Habits class:

```
import Foundation

class Habits: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Habit]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Habits")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Habits") {
            if let decodeItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: savedItems) {
                items = decodeItems
                return
            }
        }
        
        items = []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare the model classes as structs and remove `ObservableObject`
2. [Not directly related] Declare `trackingData` as non-optional empty array otherwise it crashes – or nothing happens – if you are going to append items. And remove the nil-coalescing operators
3. Change the `ForEach` line to

   ```
   ForEach($habits.items) { $habit in
   ```
4. Now you can modify the items for example

   ```
   habit.trackingData.append(Habit.TrackingData(id: Date.now))
   ```

Side note:

The naming `Habits` - `Habit` is a bit confusing. Name the view model for example `HabitViewModel`